# Why can't MongoDB can't find my db folder?

Tags: database, mongodb

I'm trying to run `mongo` locally on my MacOS and have been having some issues. I've installed the community edition with `brew`.

I create a `data/db` folder using `sudo mkdir -p /data/db`. However, when I run `mongod --dbpath="~/data/db"` in the terminal I get the following error:

```
{"t":{"$date":"2021-05-04T15:59:11.085-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23285,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-05-04T15:59:11.105-04:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22601,   "ctx":"main","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-05-04T15:59:11.106-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4648602, "ctx":"main","msg":"Implicit TCP FastOpen in use."}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-05-04T15:59:11.110-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4615611, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"MongoDB starting","attr":{"pid":35628,"port":27017,"dbPath":"~/data/db","architecture":"64-bit","host":"Carloss-MBP.home"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-05-04T15:59:11.110-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23403,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Build Info","attr":{"buildInfo":{"version":"4.4.5","gitVersion":"ff5cb77101b052fa02da43b8538093486cf9b3f7","modules":[],"allocator":"system","environment":{"distarch":"x86_64","target_arch":"x86_64"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-05-04T15:59:11.110-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":51765,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Operating System","attr":{"os":{"name":"Mac OS X","version":"20.3.0"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-05-04T15:59:11.110-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":21951,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Options set by command line","attr":{"options":{"storage":{"dbPath":"~/data/db"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-05-04T15:59:11.114-04:00"},"s":"E",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":20557,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"DBException in initAndListen, terminating","attr":{"error":"NonExistentPath: Data directory ~/data/db not found. Create the missing directory or specify another path using (1) the --dbpath command line option, or (2) by adding the 'storage.dbPath' option in the configuration file."}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-05-04T15:59:11.115-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":4784900, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Stepping down the ReplicationCoordinator for shutdown","attr":{"waitTimeMillis":10000}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-05-04T15:59:11.116-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"COMMAND",  "id":4784901, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the MirrorMaestro"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-05-04T15:59:11.116-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"SHARDING", "id":4784902, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the WaitForMajorityService"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-05-04T15:59:11.116-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":20562,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutdown: going to close listening sockets"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-05-04T15:59:11.116-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4784905, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the global connection pool"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-05-04T15:59:11.116-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4784906, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the FlowControlTicketholder"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-05-04T15:59:11.116-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":20520,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Stopping further Flow Control ticket acquisitions."}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-05-04T15:59:11.247-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4784918, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the ReplicaSetMonitor"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-05-04T15:59:11.247-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"SHARDING", "id":4784921, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the MigrationUtilExecutor"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-05-04T15:59:11.247-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784925, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down free monitoring"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-05-04T15:59:11.247-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4784927, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the HealthLog"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-05-04T15:59:11.247-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4784929, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Acquiring the global lock for shutdown"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-05-04T15:59:11.247-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":4784931, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Dropping the scope cache for shutdown"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-05-04T15:59:11.258-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"FTDC",     "id":4784926, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down full-time data capture"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-05-04T15:59:11.258-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20565,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Now exiting"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-05-04T15:59:11.258-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23138,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down","attr":{"exitCode":100}}
```

Not sure what the problem is here. I also attempted to run `mongo` and get the following output:

```
MongoDB shell version v4.4.5
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017 :: caused by :: Connection refused :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:374:17
@(connect):2:6
exception: connect failed
exiting with code 1
```

Am I missing something? Did I create the `db` folder in the wrong path?

Comment: It looks like you've created a directory from root: `/data/db` Then tried to reference it with `~/data/db` which is based off of your home directory, not root.

Comment: @RQDQ just did, same result unfrotunately.

Comment: Using `~/data/db` is not very smart, because it depends on the current user. I assume MongoDB does not resolve the home `~` symbol, use the absolute path name.

Comment: Did you grant write permissions on `/data/db` to mongo user?

Comment: Hmm, I'm trying to create the `data/db` folder in the right place but I'm getting confused. Couldn't create it with `sudo mkdir -p /data/db/` in `usr/local/bin` where all the executables are.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I was able to run it by specifying the dbpath to `usr/local/var/mongo/data/db`